# Retrieve data from incoming request before completion in .NET/C#/Razor/IIS

Tags: c#, .net, post, iis, intercept

I have a .NET/C#/Razor application running under IIS. When users upload one or more large files I would like to start processing before the upload completes. Is there any way to gain access to the incomplete data in the POST request - or the  raw POST data - as soon as it arrives at the server?

I tried the Filters, but those seem to be only activated after completion.

```
namespace Foo.ActionFilters
{
    public class UploadFilter : ActionFilterAttribute
    {
        public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Start OnActionExecuting");
            var incomingBytes = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.InputStream;
        }            

    }   
}
```

Comment: please also specified what you have tried some code.

Comment: I have added the code. The code works, but is only executed after completion. I would like the partial data as soon as it arrives.